# Pretty print XmlTextWriter in C++

Tags: xml, c++-cli, tidy

I wrote this code:

```
            XmlTextWriter^ w = gcnew XmlTextWriter( fs, nullptr );
        w->WriteProcessingInstruction("xml", "version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"");
        w->WriteStartElement("healing");
            w->WriteStartElement("health1");
                w->WriteElementString("value", "100");
                w->WriteElementString("hotkey", "2");
                w->WriteElementString("enable", "0");
            w->WriteEndElement();
            w->WriteStartElement("health2");
                w->WriteElementString("value", "100");
                w->WriteElementString("hotkey", "2");
                w->WriteElementString("enable", "0");
            w->WriteEndElement();
            w->WriteStartElement("health3");
                w->WriteElementString("value", "100");
                w->WriteElementString("hotkey", "2");
                w->WriteElementString("enable", "0");
            w->WriteEndElement();
            w->WriteStartElement("mana");
                w->WriteElementString("value", "100");
                w->WriteElementString("hotkey", "2");
                w->WriteElementString("enable", "0");
            w->WriteEndElement();
        w->WriteEndElement();
        w->Flush();
        w->Close();
```

But it's creating XML which is not pretty looking, without enter, tabs etc:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><healing><health1><value>100</value><hotkey>2</hotkey><enable>0</enable></health1><health2><value>100</value><hotkey>2</hotkey><enable>0</enable></health2><health3><value>100</value><hotkey>2</hotkey><enable>0</enable></health3><mana><value>100</value><hotkey>2</hotkey><enable>0</enable></mana></healing>
```

How can I make it look pretty?

Comment: What did you mean with the tag "net"? I removed it.

Comment: @user1100671: You can use the `c++-cli` tag for that.

Comment: this is useful for any code that runs on top of .NET Framework, not just C++/CLI but others too (C#, VB.NET etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you want to set the [Formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextwriter.formatting.aspx) property on the XmlTextWriter.